# number of unique elements excluding NA in r

Tags: r

I am looking to count the number of unique elements in a vector, but excluding NA elements.

Basically, I want to use something like `length(unique(x))` with an na.rm=TRUE argument, so that if I have `length(unique(c(1,2,3,NA,2)))` will return `3`

I tried data.table `uniqueN` but this also doesn't have this option. Is there a quick and easy way to do this, instead of having to do two separate operations on the column?

Comment: I think you want `na.omit()`.  I think `length(unique(na.omit(x)))` would work for you.  Or just use `x[!is.na(x)]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`data.table::uniqueN` has `na.rm` in version v1.9.7+.

Answer (score 35):

You can use `na.omit` first:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,NA,2)
length(unique(na.omit(x)))
```

Alternatively, `n_distinct` from dplyr has an `na_rm` argument:

```
library(dplyr)
n_distinct(x, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for na.omit(x) tip. It helps me!